# How to put IF CONDITION with an AND CONDITION and the NOT OPERATOR in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
 <body>
  <input type="radio" name="other_charges" value="To Pay" >To Pay
 <input type="radio"  name="other_charges" value="COD"  >COD
 <input type="submit" onclick="sum_cash()"/>
</body>
```

here is my html ...in this i am having two radio buttons with different values  and i have called a function using onclick event....here is the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sum_cash() {
      var elements_ocharges = document.getElementsByName('other_charges');

      for (var i = 0; i < elements_ocharges.length; i++) {

        if (elements_ocharges[i].checked)
          value_ocharges = elements_ocharges[i].value;
      }
      var val_ocharges=value_ocharges;

      if (val_ocharges=="To Pay") {
        alert("pay");   
      }

      if (val_ocharges=="COD") {
        alert("cod");   
      }

      if ((val_ocharges!="COD") && (val_ocharges!="To Pay") ) {
        alert("hi");    
      }
    }
</script>
```

Now in the function, I am checking the value of the radio button selected. If the user chooses the **Pay** radio button then on clicking the submit button it alerts the user for payment. When the user chooses the **COD** radio button then on submitting it alerts COD.

What I want is that when the user has selected nothing and clicked on the submit button then it should alert the user. Unfortunately, it is not checking the condition. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please declare `var val_ocharges` at the top of the function. It will make your code simple to read and avoid hoisting related issues

Comment: This looks fine: `if ((val_ocharges!="COD") && (val_ocharges!="To Pay") )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sum_cash()
  {
    var elements_ocharges = document.getElementsByName('other_charges');

    var value_ocharges = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements_ocharges.length; i++)
    {
      if (elements_ocharges[i].checked)
        value_ocharges = elements_ocharges[i].value;
    }
    var val_ocharges=value_ocharges;

 if(val_ocharges=="To Pay")
 {
    alert("pay");   
  }
 else if(val_ocharges=="COD")
 {
   alert("cod");    
 }
 else
 {
   alert("hi"); 
 }  }
</script>
```

Comment: like this it not alerting anything

Comment: @user3138522:- Could you please try to declare your `var value_ocharges = null;` at the top of your function and try again!

Comment: @RahulTripathi—that will make no difference whatsoever since all variable declarations are processed before any code is executed, and initialising *value_ocharges* to *null* doesn't make any difference since its value is replaced before any logic uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
else if ((val_ocharges =="")

     {
       alert("hi"); 
     }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The value of a form control is always a string, so `val_ocharges == null` will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this conditional near the top:

```
if (elements_ocharges[i].checked)
       value_ocharges = elements_ocharges[i].value;
```

since neither radio button is checked, `value_ocharges` is never set. this will cause an error when you attempt to access the value with `var val_ocharges=value_ocharges;` you should set the value of `value_ocharges` to something (`null` is fine) before entering your loop, then everything will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sum_cash()
  {
    var elements_ocharges = document.getElementsByName('other_charges');

    var value_ocharges = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements_ocharges.length; i++)
    {
      if (elements_ocharges[i].checked)
        value_ocharges = elements_ocharges[i].value;
    }
    var val_ocharges=value_ocharges;
    if(val_ocharges=="To Pay")
    {
      alert("pay");   
    }

    if(val_ocharges=="COD")
    {
      alert("cod");    
    }
    if ((val_ocharges!="COD") && (val_ocharges!="To Pay") )
    {
      alert("hi"); 
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, set your `value_ocharges` above the for loop:

```
var value_ocharges = false;
```

Then, instead of:

```
if ((val_ocharges!="COD") && (val_ocharges!="To Pay") ) {
    alert("hi"); 
}
```

use this outside of the loop:

```
if (!val_ocharges){
    alert("hi");
}
```

Basically, this checks if `val_ocharges` is defined somewhere in the loop, and if it's not, it triggers the alert.